# What does 'normal normal medium 45px/61px Oswald' mean in a css font rule?

Tags: css, adobe-xd

I'm working on converting a design in Adobe Xd to a HTML template, for one element its suggesting the following css rules.

```
top: 149px;
left: 54px;
width: 463px;
height: 208px;
text-align: left;
font: normal normal medium 45px/61px Oswald; 
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: uppercase;
opacity: 1;
```

Btw, I am familiar with the font shorthand like `font: italic small-caps bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;` and it works too but what is this new format that Xd is suggesting? Even Chrome is finding it as `invalid`.

[image: Font invalid]

[image: Font shorthand issue]

Comment: What don't you understand about it? The information given in the MDN documentation for the [`font` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) seems to give useful information.

Comment: That doesn't explain why its invalid ?

Comment: But your question - as you asked it - is: "What does '`normal normal medium 45px/61px Oswald`' mean in a css font rule?" which MDN explains; you may wish to edit your question to make it clear what your specific question is.

Comment: Try putting font-family value (Oswald) in the beginning of the rule

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica ok Updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shorthand syntax for the `font` property translates to:

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;
```

So that generated code is equivalent to:

```
/* font: normal normal medium 45px/61px Oswald; */

font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: medium;
font-size: 45px;
line-height: 61px;
font-family: Oswald;
```

The invalid property here is `font-weight`, which [can't accept "medium" as a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight). "Medium" is an OpenType value that roughly corresponds to `font-weight: 500`, but isn't a valid CSS value.

This is a useful debugging technique for future reference: if you ever run into the `invalid property value` error when using CSS shorthand, it's helpful to rewrite the shorthand property as individual properties, which then lets the browser's devtools point out exactly which property has an invalid value.

Comment: Ahh makes sense, Thanks.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for the nifty tip.

Comment: It was a subtle error! I initially read right past my own `font-weight: medium` line without realizing that was the invalid bit.